# Google Kubernetes Engine: Failed to create an ingress error

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I tried to create an ingress with hello world app here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes-engine-samples/tree/main/hello-app. But I received an error: Failed to create an ingress. Ingress.extensions "hello-world-ingress" is invalid: spec: Invalid value: []networking.IngressRule(nil): either `defaultBackend` or `rules` must be specified".
[GKE Failed to create an ingress screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r28NR.png)

But last two weeks, I can create an ingress with this app and It worked perfectly.

Comment: `helloweb-backend` default backed is. not sure why you are using console when you have yaml config. try by applying yaml once `kubectl apply -f filename`

Comment: @HarshManvar, I'll try with yaml file, I think it should work. But I don't know why the console UI does not work. I tried many times the last two weeks and it worked properly.